# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that needs to be on a single one:

```
SELECT call_queues.queue_alias, count(users.*) as free
       FROM call_queues
       INNER JOIN call_queues_users ON call_queues.id = call_queues_users.call_queue_id
       INNER JOIN users ON call_queues_users.user_id = users.id
       WHERE users.phone_status_id = 0
         AND users.status_id = 1
       GROUP BY call_queues.queue_alias
```

That query returns something like this:

```
     queue_alias     | free 
---------------------+---------------
 Teste Rodolfo       |             1
 Teste Diego         |             1
 Desenvolvimento     |             1
 Suporte Emergencial |             1
 Gestores            |             1
```

And another one:

```
SELECT call_queues.queue_alias, count(users.*) as disconnected
FROM call_queues
INNER JOIN call_queues_users ON call_queues.id = call_queues_users.call_queue_id
INNER JOIN users ON call_queues_users.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.phone_status_id = 4
  AND users.status_id <> 2
GROUP BY call_queues.queue_alias
```

That returns:

```
     queue_alias      | disconnected 
----------------------+--------------
 Comercial Emergencia |            1
 Comercial            |            1
 Comunicação          |            1
 Testes Flawbson      |            1
```

When I join this two queries on a single select:

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT COUNT(users.*)
   FROM call_queues
   INNER JOIN call_queues_users ON call_queues.id = call_queues_users.call_queue_id
   INNER JOIN users ON call_queues_users.user_id = users.id
   WHERE users.phone_status_id = 0
     AND users.status_id = 1
   GROUP BY call_queues.queue_alias) AS free,

  (SELECT count(users.*)
   FROM call_queues
   INNER JOIN call_queues_users ON call_queues.id = call_queues_users.call_queue_id
   INNER JOIN users ON call_queues_users.user_id = users.id
   WHERE users.phone_status_id = 4
     AND users.status_id <> 2
   GROUP BY call_queues.queue_alias) AS disconnected;
```

I got the error message in the title.

I assume the problem is that the queries returns different number of rows.

The result of the query should be:

```
     queue_alias      | disconnected | free
----------------------+--------------+---------
 Comercial Emergencia |            1 |       0
 Comercial            |            1 |       0
 Comunicação          |            1 |       0
 Testes Flawbson      |            1 |       0
 Teste Rodolfo        |            0 |       1
 Teste Diego          |            0 |       1
 Desenvolvimento      |            0 |       1
 Suporte Emergencial  |            0 |       1
 Gestores             |            0 |       1
```

So, if the error message is not about what i think, how can i do the result above in db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you have a `group by` in the subqueries.  So, under many circumstances, the subqueries will return more than one row.

Instead, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT q.queue_alias,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.phone_status_id = 0 AND u.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as free,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.phone_status_id = 4 AND u.status_id <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as disconnected
FROM call_queues q INNER JOIN
     call_queues_users qu
     ON q.id = qu.call_queue_id INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON cq.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY q.queue_alias;
```